# Shared Element Transition Crashing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have a RecyclerView Adapter from which there is an intent to the next Activity

Transition Exit code :

```
    public ViewHolderEvents onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition));
    }

    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_event_row, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolderEvents viewHolder =new ViewHolderEvents(view);

    return viewHolder;
}`
```

Calling Next Activity:

```
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
                    ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, view.findViewById(R.id.imageView), view.findViewById(R.id.imageView).getTransitionName());
                    ActivityCompat.startActivity((Activity)context, intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
                }
                else
                {context.startActivity(intent);}
```

There seems to be no issue when pressing a card while first entering the app. But if I use the search (which is another Activity ) and then come back to the main activity, Then on clicking any card the app crashes

Logcat:

```
    Process: com.squaredbytes.eventlane, PID: 23576
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1544)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:4504)
        at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5381)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3780)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4023)
        at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivity(ActivityCompatJB.java:26)
        at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity(ActivityCompat.java:98)
        at app.EventAdapter$ViewHolderEvents$1.onClick(EventAdapter.java:142)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Is there a fix for this?